# CSS in reactJS application does not apply text color

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making use of navbar in my reactJS application.  I use it to place a dynamic string to the right of the menu icon.  I created a className to control the color of the text string and to limit the length of the string (since it is dynamic and I dont want it scrolling or running into the menu icon).  I am able to limit the length in my new className but for some reason, the text color is not being applied.  When I launch the application and make use of the developer tools, I look at the elements to see what css is being applied.  I noticed that in the definition of my custom className, the text attribute has a line through it.  So, for some reason, the browser has decided to not apply the color attribute.  Here is a screen print of the page which shows the classNames that are in play here.

[image]

This is the HTML code that is executing:

```
<div className="planNameandMenu">
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand jrsClass" href="#">{this.state.planName}</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler bg-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                 <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
             </button>
         {this.renderMenu()}
     </nav>
 </div>
```

These are my custom classes:

```
.planNameandMenu {
    background-color: #3B5796;
}

.jrsClass {
    max-width: 225px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The problem here seems to be the [specifity of the CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):  `.navbar-light .navbar-brand` has a higher specifity than `.jrsClass`.

Comment: your `navbar` imported from library ? or it's your implementation from scratch ?

Comment: Important Side Note after you implementing one of the solutions: make sure that your importing your custom styles after importing 3rd party libraries styles. to make sure your css  will override it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the specificity of your rules as noted by @Alvaro in the comments.

Two options:

1. Target .navbar-light .navbar-brand

```
    .navbar-light .navbar-brand {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

2. Add 'important' to .jrsClass

```
      .jrsClass {
        max-width: 225px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Adding !important was the easiest fix!

Comment: The important will fix this bug but it's not a good practice. Try to use  ".navbar-light  .jrsClass". This will give for your class higher priority

Answer (score 1):

In the picture you attach you can see that another `color` rule is being applied through CSS:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
```

This selector has a specificity value higher than `.jrsClass`. That is why your style is not being applied.

You can set the rules for your class with the selector:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand.jrsClass {
    max-width: 225px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

so that your `color` rule is applied.